# Multiple data structures over the same objects

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

Let Person be a class with attributes name, age and idNumber. I want to have a collection of "Persons", and I want to be able to perform the following operations in the most efficient way:

1. Retrieve them by their idNumber.
2. Get a list of the Persons where age > X.
3. Get a list of all the persons sorted alphabetically by name.

My idea is to simultaneously maintain a Hashmap using the id as key and two Treemaps using age and name as keys for each of the TreeMaps.

1. Is this the best way?
2. Is it necessary to remove a person from the age TreeMap before editing the age to then put it back in?
3. If answer to question 2 is yes, how do I handle that when that persons are being used and potentially being edited on multiple places?

Comment: If `id` is going to be (mostly) continuous, you might as well use a plain array.

Comment: It's the "national identification number", not really continuous :)

Comment: For the name, you should consider using a [`trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: I don't get how a prefix tree helps me here. I don't want a collection of names, but a collection of objects with names. How do i do that on a Trie?

Comment: This is homework, right?

Comment: You want to index by name, right? Make a trie that has a list of people with a given name at the appropriate place, just like you'd have in any other key-value system -  hashmaps, other types of trees, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple indexes for a Java Collection - most basic solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501449/multiple-indexes-for-a-java-collection-most-basic-solution)

Comment: It's not homework, just ran into a discussion with a friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the best way?

I would say that using a relational database and proper indexing is the best way, but if you want to do this in-memory, then yes - you are sacrificing memory for performance.

> Is it necessary to remove a person from the age TreeMap before editing the age to then put it back in?

Yes. The position of an item in a tree is determined once when it is added. If the comparable property (`age` or `name`) changes, the `TreeMap` won't magically discover that and move the object. This will most likely cause inability to find element in a map even though it's there.

> If answer to question 2 is yes, how do I handle that when that persons are being used and potentially being edited on multiple places?

Prefer immutable objects so it is not possible to alter an object already placed in a tree. If for any reason you can not afford for that, consider [observer](/questions/tagged/observer) pattern - when storing a `Person` in a map, register a listener in that `Person`. When e.g. `age` changes, the listener notifies a tree (or another observer) storing people by age and handles removal and adding back.

BTW if you try to remove an object *after* it was modifed, you will fail - `TreeMap` will no longer be able to find an object to be removed...