# Typesafe Multiple key types for Map

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to see if I can use to implement a Map that can accept two different **Classes** using generics like the one specified in [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)

I tried

```
public class LocalizedStringMap extends ConcurrentHashMap<Locale & String, String> {
```

But that came up as a syntax error.  The closest thing I can do is just make a separate method that will `getByLocale()` instead.

Comment: `public class LocalizedStringMap extends ConcurrentHashMap<T extends Locale & String, String> {`?

Comment: @GBlodgett only interfaces, not classes can be extended this way

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano what is your actual goal? Maybe you need a complex key like `Pair<Locale, String>` or multiple indices like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501449/multiple-indexes-for-a-java-collection-most-basic-solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, this can't be done. Generics handles type boxing and compile-time type checking for you. Using your example, keySet() would return a Set object with both Locale and String members, with no way to enforce type checking or handle unboxing.

The example you cited only works for a single class and one or more interfaces, but does not work for more than one class.