# How can I make a search box in Java

Tags: java, awt, japplet, search-box

I'm making a program in Java which users can login and upload data to certain people in the program. But, I want to make a search bar so someone can type 'Joe' and it would show anyone with the name 'Joe' in a file. Each name that is registered will be made a file so 'Joe Rico' would have a folder named 'Joe Rico'. I plan to use AWT for the GUI system if that matters and this will be a Java applet if that matters also. (The file system will be stored on the web-server and certain users will have certain permissions). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have tried using arrays and such. Just wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Well. I can't at the moment. I'm at school eating lunch.

Comment: take a box and label it search :P

Comment: Well.... I guess I didn't think this through :P

Comment: Sad.. Already got -2 votes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187888/java-searching-within-a-list-of-objects

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's why I got the -votes.. :P I'll make sure to search better.

Comment: Avoid -1s by providing some code that shows what you've been trying and why it doesn't work, etc. Your question is pretty general and would require much information to answer properly as a search box has many elements. Are you asking how to place a text box in a window, how to parse the string input, how to search a file, how to make the record, or show the results? Don't use AWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of issues here, and your question is very vague - you could be asking any of the following questions:

1. **How do I make a search *box*?**

   You're asking how to properly implement a search box in AWT.  First off, use Swing, it's a lot nicer.  From there, resources like [How to use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) will be very helpful.
2. **How do I make a search application?**

   You're asking how to implement searching behavior in a GUI.  In this case, the key concept you need to understand is [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which will let you compartmentalize your business logic from your graphical interface in a clean and efficient way.
3. **How do I efficiently search data?**

   You're asking for data structures that are good for searching.  The classic answer is a [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or a binary search algorithm, like [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29), which allows you to search in `O(log n)` time.  This may or may not be enough for your use case, but another possible option is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), which provides fast prefix-searching.  If these basic data structures aren't good enough for your use case, read on.
4. **How do I store data for efficient searches?**

   Very much dependent on exactly what you're trying to do, but the concept is called [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  Java provides serialization behavior natively, however I personally vastly prefer using JSON, and Google's awesome [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library makes this quite painless.
5. **What tools exist to provide search behavior for me?**

   If answer #3 wasn't good enough, you're looking for something more powerful.  You've got two basic choices, depending on your needs.  Either a [Relational Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database), or a [Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm)/Index library.  There are countless database options out there, but I like [H2](http://www.h2database.com) for quick Java work.  A proper search tool like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is almost certainly overkill for your needs, but the option exists.

I hope some of this answers your question.  In the future, try to create questions that can have a concrete answer.  Questions that are open-ended and leave the notion of "answered" undefined are very difficult to properly address.