# JPA for querying in-memory data

Tags: java, jpa, in-memory-database

During an import procedure, I read tabular data from excel sheets. 
I want to perform some operation on this data: I want to sort, search by key, filter etc. 
Is it possible to reliably perform this kind of operations via JQL?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Space4J](http://www.space4j.org/) and simple Collections for something like this.

Personally I think all these ORM abstractions and layers are a distraction at the small scale problem domains, and are inflexible and added complexity at the other extreme.

Comment: Very intresting, but is just a 0.9 release!

Comment: that means very little, it is how long it has been around which is more important than version numbers

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: From what I've read in the home page of Space4J, I got the impression that Space4J lets you handle a persistent database as Java collections. But then don't you lose the ability to perform queries over this database, which is precisely what AgostinoX wants to do?

Comment: yes, it is quite exactly what I'm searching for. The problem is that was an "implicit" requisite: use something "consolidated", or better "consolid" something (like jpa) that would benefit of another case study. Obviously, not over stretching its purpose.

Comment: @JB Nizet:Space4j offers indexation so you can effectively query huge amounts of data. Take a look: http://forum.space4j.org/posts/list/5.page

Answer (score 1):

You could use an in-memory database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), fill it, then use JPA to query the data. But wouldn't using some Maps and Lists be sufficient?

Comment: I started thinking of Collections, so Maps or Lists of "MyRecord". Then I asked myself whether instead of maintaining myself the set of MyRecord instances, i let the JPA runtime do the job, I get some advantage.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like because I also think that a solution with JPA and an underlying db may be a bit heavy-handed...

Answer (score 1):

[DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) has its own in-memory query evaluator for JDOQL and JPQL syntaxis. I've never used it outside of a full JDO / JPA persistence environment but there's no real reason why it couldn't be made to work with a little coding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EclipseLink, you can execute most queries in memory against the cache.

You just need to read everything into the cache they execute a JPQL or Criteria query with the "CheckCacheOnly" option.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Options