# Any effective opensource alternative to IBM purequery to query in-memory collections?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Do we have some opensource alternatives to IBM pureQuery to query in-memory collections of the Java Collection Framework, or composite Java objects?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're asking if there's an OSS alternative to pureQuery and whether pureQuery works on in-memory DS of the Java Collection Framework, of if you want an OSS aternative that does work on in-memory collections, including specifically the Java Collections Framework.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in my comment, I am not entirely sure I understand your question: I'm not sure whether you're asking if there's an OSS alternative to pureQuery and whether pureQuery works on in-memory DS of the Java Collection Framework, of if you want an OSS aternative that does work on in-memory collections, including specifically the Java Collections Framework.

But, I'll git it a try...

## Persistence-Layer Query Languages / Frameworks

If you're looking for an open source software for query-base interaction with a persistence layer, the obvious solutions are quite simply:

- the [Java Persistence Query Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html),
- the [Hibernate Query language (HQL)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html),
- the [Java Data Objects (JDO) Query Language (JDOQL)](http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdoql.html).

Note that these could be used on an in-memory database as well (like H2 or HSQLDb).

## Collections Query Languages / Frameworks

However, if you want to query collections, there are a few projects, like:

- [the java Query Language (JQL)](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~djp/jql/) language extension:

  ```
  ArrayList<String> words = dict.getWords(Puzzle.MEDIUM);
  ArrayList<Integer> gaplengths = puzzle.getGapLengths();

  List<Object[]> matches = selectAll(
      String w : words, 
      Integer i : gaplengths | w.length() == i);
  ```
- [the Stack-Based Query Language for Java (sqbl4j)](http://code.google.com/p/sbql4j/) language extension:

  ```
  List<Product> products = getProductList();
  List<Product> expensiveInStockProducts = #{
      products 
      where unitsInStock > 0 and unitPrice > 3.00
  };
  ```
- [Java Objects SQL (JoSQL)](http://josql.sourceforge.net/):

  ```
  List myObjs = getMyObjects ();
  Query q = new Query ();
  q.parse ("SELECT * FROM java.io.File WHERE name LIKE '%.java'");
  QueryResults qr = q.execute (myObjs);
  List res = qr.getResults ();
  ```
- [jxpath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/), for a different approach with XPath expressions:

  ```
  Address address = (Address)JXPathContext
      .newContext(vendor)
      .getValue("locations[address/zipCode='90210']/address");
  ```
- Functional programming libraries for Java provide similar features, in that they give you access to the basic functional constructs `filter`, `map`, `collect`, `transform` etc... For instance, with:

  - [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

    ```
    Set<String> strings = buildSetStrings();  
    Collection<String> filteredStrings =
        Collections2.filter(strings, Predicates.containsPattern("^J"));
    ```
  - [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/):

    ```
    Array<Integer> a = array(97, 44, 67, 3, 22, 90, 1, 77, 98, 1078, 6, 64, 6, 79, 42);
    final Array<Integer> b = a.filter(even);
    ```
  - [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/):

    ```
    // with normal interfaces:
    List<Person> buyersSortedByAges = sort(
        extract(
            select(sales, having(on(Sale.class).getValue(), greaterThan(50000)))
        ), on(Sale.class).getBuyer() 
    ), on(Person.class).getAge());

    // with fluent/chainable intefaces:
    List<Person> buyersSortedByAges = with(sales)
        .retain(having(on(Sale.class).getValue(), greaterThan(50000)))
        .extract(on(Sale.class).getBuyer())
        .sort(on(Person.class).getAge());
    ```

---

Or maybe you were just looking for this tutorial on [querying in-memory collections with pureQuery](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dstudio/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.datatools.javatool.runtime.doc/topics/cpdqrunqrycol.html)?

Comment: Thanks! It would be cool if you could update your answer since it contains many projects which seem to be unmaintained. And maybe there are some new options now? Like CQEngine mentioned below...

Answer (score 2):

Also CQEngine, which supports indexing as well as querying: [CQEngine](http://code.google.com/p/cqengine/).

For more background see similar question: [How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like/11712925#11712925)