# Using javax.management.* api in Hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, javabeans

Just curious,What is the use of below `imports` in java.I'm wrongly imported while doing hibernate stuff and those are not `compatible` with `hibernate`.

```
import javax.management.Query;
import javax.management.QueryExp;
```

I gone through the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/Query.html) and found in that they can fire queries on the `beans`.

Can i use them on my hibernate pojo(to avoid some memory eat up)??or I understood in a wrong way ??

Any idea about them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I gone through the api and found in that they can fire queries on the beans.

Not exactly. [API Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/Query.html) states:

> The MBean Server can be queried for MBeans that meet a particular condition, using its queryNames or queryMBeans method

So, it's not exactly about regular pojos. `MBean` or `managed bean` is one of the concepts introduced by Java Management Extensions (JMX) technology. As [JMX Technology Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/overview/instrumentation.html#wp998816) states:

> The Java objects that implement resources and their instrumentation are called managed beans, or MBeans. MBeans must follow the design patterns and interfaces defined in the JMX specification (JSR 3). This ensures that all MBeans provide the instrumentation of managed resources in a standardized way.

Basically MBeans are used to extend standard JVM management functionality. So, developers can integrate application-specific options to standard monitoring tools (jconsole) and, thus, simplify and standardize resource administration.

[Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/Query.html) is just a utility class that introduce several methods used to build [QueryExps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/QueryExp.html). QueryExp objects are used [to query MBeansServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#queryNames%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.QueryExp%29).

> > Can i use them on my hibernate pojo(to avoid some memory eat up)?

Well, they aren't meant to be used that way. So, using them for such a purposes will just introduce confusion.

If you are looking for a way to query your pojos (I don't understand how does it help with memory eat up, though), check out these questions:

- [How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like)
- [What is the Java equivalent for LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217228/what-is-the-java-equivalent-for-linq)

Answer (score 1):

They are part of the [JMX Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html). I don't think using them without the framework would make sense.

Comment: Nevermind then. I had the impression you stumbled upon them by accident.